# What data structure to choose for an ELO rating system with 20k+ entries?

Tags: java, data-structures, tree

I have some Objects (currently 20 000 +) that have the following Attributes

```
Object
----------
String name
int    rating
```

I want to create an ELO rating for all these Objects. This implies the following:

1. To adjust the ELO of 2 Objects matched against each other I need to find those Objects in the list by `name`.
2. To Display the List I need to get every Object ordered by its `rating`.

The whole program will be implemented in Java, but I think its independent from the programming language.

Currently I am unsure which data model to choose for this Project. A friend advised me to use a 2-4 tree to insert the Objects ordered by `name` so I can change the rating of each object fast.

However the Objects are printed in order of their `rating` rather than by name and I don't want to sort so many Objects every time I output the list.

As I am pretty new to data structures: What is the usual way to solve this problem? 
Creating another tree ordered by `rating`? 
Having a list of `ratings` and each rating linked to each Object currently having that rating?

Edit: ELO rating is a mapping from the set of objects to the integers. Each object only gets one rating but a rating can have multiple Objects associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Creating another tree ordered by rating? Having a list of ratings and each rating linked to each Object currently having that rating?

Well , this is one way to do so , but will take huge space also since you have 20K+ entries .

The best way i can think of now is :
Use datastructure like [multimap](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/multimap/) with `key`=`name` , and `value` = `ratings`.
This way , everytime you insert a new `object` in multimap , it will take O(logN) time .

To find all ratings with same `name` use [equal_range](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/equal_range/) , which is also an O(logN) operation .

Hope this helps !

Comment: Are you suggesting to use the multimap instead of the 2-4 tree? If yes, how do I get the objects ordered by ratings? If no, shouldn't it rather be key=`ratings` and value=`name`? So I can quickly order the Objects by rating to display them? Note that each object only has one Rating associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

A `HashMap` with name as the key will give you O(1) performance when matching the elements, keep a `TreeSet` with a rating `Comparator` and you'll have the items in order. Although you'll need to reinsert an element if the rating changes.

Comment: TreeSet won't allow you to have two Objects with the same `rating` stored at the same time, when defining the Comparator like suggested, as objects would be equal when they have the same rating.